# Dataprofiles fields mapping how to set base, thumbnail, small image via CSV file

Tags: import, csv, product-images

I am trying to import and assign images i.e base image, small, thumbnailbut i am getting errors and my images are not assigning to the products.

any help??

[image: Import errors]

[image: Field Mapping]

[image: CSV format]

Answer (score 0):

Better use xml import. With CSV i had a lot of problems with specials signs.
Maybe you also made a mistake with quotation mark.

Then your images need to be in the media/import folder with the correct name.

Comment: can you give me a reference of any example in xml ?